# How to match name if layer name contain "\f"

Tags: arcpy, python

One of my layer name is

"FullProbeWMS\fullprobewms[Heatmap] Trace Lines"

Where I check if this layer is present or not by using below code.

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.longName == "FullProbeWMS\fullprobewms\[Heatmap] Trace Lines":
        ispresnt = True
        islyr = lyr
        break
    else:
        ispresnt = False
        islyr = ""
```

However, when I run this code I always get values of "ispresnt" or "islyr" as "False" and "" because the name contains a character "\f".

How could I fix that?

I have tried many workarounds as changing values in string or single quotes etc.

Comment: Always use raw strings or escape the backslash if your string contains a backslash. i.e `r"abc\def"` or `abc\\def`

Comment: Since this is about comparing strings using Python rather than any ArcPy functions I voted to close it. Answers to pure Python questions can often be found quickly at [so].

Comment: Note: `"\f"` is the python escape sequence for an ASCII formfeed character.  Others include `"\t"` (tab character), `"\r"` (return or linefeed character), `"\n"` (newline character).  The full list is buried in the Python documentation - [2.4.1. String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)